# PHP - class property with ternary operator confsuion - could someone explain why this doesnt work

Tags: php, oop, class

I am trying to extend a base class and be able to access a property from it's child class, could someone explain why the following works:

```
class Base_Class {
        public function is_dev(){
            $var = (substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], -3) == 'dev') ? TRUE : FALSE;
            return $var;
        }
}
```

so with this i can access in child class via `$this->is_dev()`

But the following does not work:

```
class Base_Class {
        public $var = (substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], -3) == 'dev') ? TRUE : FALSE;
}
```

I was hoping to access it using `$this->var` but I am getting a syntax error which i dont understand before I get to this part.

**UPDATE:**

The error is complaining about a lot when I try this listing 5 or 6 syntax errors before it runs out of room, ending in syntax er... but the first line reads

```
expected identifier +,_,static
```

all the other are saying it expected various other things which were not there... sure does expect a lot

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what would that syntax error be?

Comment: sorry guys I have updated with error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `__construct` function. This will set `var` when the class is loaded:

```
class Base_Class {
        public $var;
        function __construct(){
            $this->var = (substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], -3) == 'dev') ? TRUE : FALSE;
        }
}
```

Comment: +1 Thanks sam, I know I can set it in a constructor, but according to the php docs example1 http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php what I'm doing looks like it should work - can you explain why it doesn't?

Comment: can you not include any logic in a property declaration outside a function?

Comment: In a sense yes. It is possible to `preset` your variables [ex: `public $foo = true`]. But you are not allowed (and I'm not sure why), predefine a variable using mathematical equations (this includes the use of parenthesis).